# Pass a model into a component test in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a component that requires an instance of a model.  The model name is WorkflowState.  How do I create an instance of workflowstate and inject into the component.

I need to create the workflow state using:

```
WorkflowState.create('some data')
```

because the constructor has some logic that need to run.

I cannot get to WorkflowState.  I tried adding an import statement like this

```
import WorkflowState from "../../../app/models/wokrflow-state";
```

but that didn't compile...

Any idea how I can do that?

My test looks something like this:

```
  var stateString = 'some data';
  var state = WorkflowState.create(JSON.parse(stateString));

  var component = this.subject({
    workflow: {state: state}
  });
  // do some testing on the component
```

Help please.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally the testing of a component should be isolated from other units, like the model in this case. You can pass a fake model that has the state you need to test specific behavior.

```
Ember.Object.create({ // the state you need })
```

And pass that to the component

If you really need to pass a real model you will have to do a lot more things, create a container and set up a store, etc. since you cannot call .create directly on a model, hopefully you can avoid all of that.